# Silicompressor no sound after video is compressed

Tags: android, compression

I have been compressing Images without any problems. Recently my app required video compress functionality to be added. Again, Silicompressor does the job but for some reason there is no audio in output file.

I am using code inside  Runnable

```
String videoUriStr; // Passed as a variable

String folderPath = activity.getExternalFilesDir("/").getAbsolutePath() + "/My Folder";
String videoPath = SiliCompressor.with(context).compressVideo(videoUriStr, folderPath);
```

I am able to play compressed video without sound (though on uploading to firebase storage, url shows black screen but right length of video. But I will figure that out). My main concern is the sound.

I have googled a lot and found 2 solutions out of which second seems to be promising but looking way to implement it.

First is to downgrade `implementation 'com.googlecode.mp4parser:isoparser:1.1.22'` to `implementation 'com.googlecode.mp4parser:isoparser:1.0.6'`, which doesn't work.

Second, which I found [here](https://github.com/Tourenathan-G5organisation/SiliCompressor/issues/65), says "issue seems to be with audio encoder, I changed audio encoder to HE_AAC it works now". Can please anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So answering my own question. Didn't get much of help on this, hence decided to switch library to [FFmpeg](http://writingminds.github.io/ffmpeg-android-java/).

Gradle

```
implementation 'com.writingminds:FFmpegAndroid:0.3.2'
```

Load Library:

```
FFmpeg fFmpeg;

private void LoadFfmpegLibrary(){
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy_hh-mm", Locale.CANADA);
    Date now = new Date();
    String videoFileName = "Video-" + formatter.format(now) + ".mp4";
    if(fFmpeg == null){
        fFmpeg = FFmpeg.getInstance(context);
        try {
            fFmpeg.loadBinary(new LoadBinaryResponseHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onStart() {
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure() {
                }

                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {
                }

                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                    Compress(videoFileName);
                }
            });
        } catch (FFmpegNotSupportedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        Compress(videoFileName);
    }
}
```

Then Compress videos

```
private void Compress(String fileName){
    String outputPath = getExternalFilesDir("/").getAbsolutePath() + "/My Folder/" + fileName;
    String[] commandArray;
    commandArray = new String[]{"-y", "-i", originalFileUriStr, "-s", "720x480", "-r", "25", "-vcodec", "mpeg4", "-b:v", "300k", "-b:a", "48000", "-ac", "2", "-ar", "22050", outputPath};
    final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
    try {
        fFmpeg.execute(commandArray, new ExecuteBinaryResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onStart() {
                dialog.setMessage("Compressing... please wait");
            }
            @Override
            public void onProgress(String message) {
                Log.e("FFmpeg onProgress? ", message);
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(String message) {
                Log.e("FFmpeg onFailure? ", message);
            }
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String message) {
                Log.e("FFmpeg onSuccess? ", message);

            }
            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                Uri compressedOutputUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(outputPath));
            }
        });
    } catch (FFmpegCommandAlreadyRunningException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And now sound works perfect.

Comment: Hi @Dev Chauhan implemented the same but not success output. Is "originalFileUriStr" string. I am getting the input from Camera out.

Comment: Did this also fix your issue of the black screen when playing but correct video length? I'm having both of the same problems

Comment: @ArnoldBrown, yes it is.

Comment: @RyanAlford, yes it did.